# How to ignore specific files/folders from eslint within NX workspaces (nrwl)

Tags: angular, eslint, nrwl

I have a huge project that we want to convert from tslint to eslint. Because its so big we want to do this in small chunks which is why we want to be able to ignore folders.  Does anyone know how to do this?

I have tried to add `"[exclude":["my main app here"]`

However when I add this exclude to the workspace.json I get an error "exclude is not found in schema" ?

I am not sure if this is the correct way to ignore these files?

any help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: The ESLint configuration file is typically called .eslintrc.json or .eslintrc.yml, not workspace.json.

Comment: @GOTO0 you are correct, I do have a .eslintrc.json file created. The issue I am having is where do I put logic to ignore certain files or folders so that eslint will not try to lint them?   Or are you saying that you would put the ignore logic within the .eslintrc.json file? If so could you show and example of how to do that?

Comment: You could maybe adapt eslint to only warn instead of error?  App will still build fine then and you can take your time to address the issues.

Comment: https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring/ignoring-code

Comment: @GOTO0 I set up the .eslingignore and added 
```{
    "ignorePatterns": [
      "**/*.ts"
    ],
    "rules": {}
}```

however this does not seem to ignore any files. Even if I set to ignore a specific file it doesn't work. It just seems to not even read this file. I fear this has something to do with the NX workspace ? So far everything I have tried has not worked :(

Any other suggestions?

Comment: @RavenMoon the file should be called ".eslintignore" and it looks like a list of file patterns, each on one line (see [an example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/eslint/eslint/main/.eslintignore)).

Answer (score 2):

The reason no answers have been accepted is that NX adds `"ignorePatterns": ["**/*"]` to the base monorepo .eslintrc and then `"ignorePatterns": ["!**/*"]` to the package .eslintrc files. I presume this is to cause only files within the package to get linted.

Unfortunately, I have not found any documentation on what `"!"` does in an eslintignore pattern. In a gitignore-like system, I could circumvent this by writing my own pattern after the `!**/*` or specifying folders at the top level.

Unfortunately, eslint differs from observing gitignore rules in this case. Someone with more insight into eslint would be able to either refer to documentation or file a bug.

Comment: I think the `!` at the beginning of the pattern is a negation or exclusion operator. In this context, I assume it means _"exclude nothing"_, So, the `"ignorePatterns": ["**/*"]` in the root .eslintrc.json file will be ignoring all files at this level, while each project's .eslintrc.json, using `"ignorePatterns": ["!**/*"]`, will be including all files within that package. Also, in the package's .eslintrc.json, we can use both rules like this: `"ignorePatterns": ["!**/*", "src/app/*"]`, meaning _"include everything but ignore all under the src/app path"_